# SQLite database returning fewer results in terminal than in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, sqlite, jupyter-notebook

I have a SQLite database with a little more than 50,000 records. In my Jupyter notebook, I can see:

```
query = 'select max(id) from table'
c.execute(query)
c.fetchall()

[(50367,)]
```

In terminal (Ubuntu 16.04), I see:

```
sqlite> select max(id) from table;
50357
```

Additionally, queries to return data with IDs between 50357 - 50367 in Jupyter do in fact return data, but they don't in the shell.

Thanks for any help, and let me know in the comments if I should add any specific info to help answer.

#### EDIT:

I've been getting this message in Jupyter

```
query = 'delete from table where id > 50357'
c.execute(query)
db.commit()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-b6e7e3eab558> in <module>()
      2 query = 'delete from table where id > 50357'
      3 c.execute(query)
----> 4 db.commit()

OperationalError: disk I/O error
```

It doesn't happen if I repeat the query a second time, but I'd also never seen it until this issue, if it provides any further clues.

Comment: Can you link you DB file?  Can you try looking at ID's <= 10 in Jupyter and shell?

Comment: Also, maybe a count of the total number of entries in the DB.

Comment: @OwenHempel tried `count` and got the same values as max(id). Just created a Dropbox link here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ixti0opto6vko7m/longform.db?dl=0. Thanks very much for the help.

Comment: @snapcrack the db link is not working? or not working for me anyways.

Comment: @jmunsch can you not get to any URL with it or does it give you the '.db files cannot be previewed' message? i got the second one and after i waited for a second i could download the db. if it's the first thing, let me know and i'll find another way

Comment: @snapcrack i get `This site can’t be reached`

Comment: @jmunsch try https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B90qb2J7ZLYrMmJ2QUtJTlBPTkE